# What Transfer Protocol for "Streaming over USB"

Tags: fpga, protocol

I'm programming the FPGA on the Red Pitaya and I'm using it for gathering datas and generating images with those datas. Then, I need to transfer the images to an Android device.
I so need to use the USB port (for connecting the board to an Android device) and I was wondering what transfer protocol I should use for the image transfer. UDP over USB? Serial over USB? Other?

Or maybe something already exists on the Red Pitaya?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Either bulk or isochronous transfers.

Comment: If you've got local storage for the images as you generate them, maybe present as a mass storage device?

Comment: Most special-purpose USB devices seem to present themselves as serial adapters, since that's a simple and well-supported protocol. I don't know if it has support on Android, though. (Another factor for them choosing this is probably the availability of FTDI USB-to-serial interface chips)

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
If I'm not wrong, it's more isochronous than bulk as I would like to do a streaming... Which answers to pjc50.
For the Android device part, a usb a to usb b is enough if I'm not wrong. I saw some apps to do the job. The remaining problem still on the RP side of the communication.

Comment: Do you have the ability to write your own drivers and load them onto the android device, or do you have to pretend to be a device which is already known to the kernel?

Comment: I need to appear as an existing module (If you are talking about the board) for the Android Device.

Comment: What is the electronics design question here?

Comment: Lots of wrong information in the comments!  Android doesn't really support standard USB devices apart from things like keyboard/mice, you have to have an app which brings its own userspace implementation of a USB "driver", conversely that means you can use basically any scheme you want as whatever you use you have to supply the code that implements it.

Comment: USB UVC is a good choice for video streaming. Raw USB is also a OK choice if don't care about compatibility. Or ethernet/serial over USB.

Answer (score -1):

look for FT232h ftdi converter... even if you dont have on your board , you can interface it with spare I/Os... you may find cheap breakout boards in ebay or aliexpress...

Im not 100% sure , but i think there is some driver for android...

Answer (score -1):

There is already an [FTDI RS232 converter](http://forum.redpitaya.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=558) on your board, wired to one of the micro-USB sockets. If the amount of data you want to transfer is moderate, you can use that. You could expect to get 1Mbit/s through such a converted, sometimes a bit more. I don't own such a board so this is just an estimate.

If you need to transfer lots of data and 1Mbit/s is not enough, you should be using Ethernet over USB. See if you have a kernel module called [`g_ether`](http://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_use_USB_device_networking) available for your kernel.

Comment: The RS422 versions of the FTDI converters I have used can get up to just about 3Mbps.

Comment: FTP is a completely unsuitable protocol for streaming data. It's aimed at transferring _files_, not arbitrary data, and is relatively complex to implement. HTTP might be a better fit, as it at least has some provisions for streaming data.

Comment: @duskwuff The OP specifically mentions transferring images to an Android device. What's wrong with transferring these as files?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev The question title specifically asks for a solution for "*streaming* over USB". FTP is not a streaming protocol.

Comment: @uuser39382 Images are not a suitable kind of data for streaming to begin with. It's either still images as files or video as a stream.